# Make input of type field send data in base64 rather than binary

Tags: javascript, html, html4

I'm writing a simple upload form in html4. It's a very simple process, usually. The problem I'm running into, is for the image data, the server is expecting base64 and will process anything I send it as base64, resulting in corrupt images. Is there some kind of attribute I can set for my form? If not, could I set up some javascript to encode the data into base64 before sending it to the server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript

Comment: the problem with that is it uses a canvas, which, as far as I'm aware, is html 5 only, and I need to be able to do everything in html 4.

Comment: It may be hard. Even impossible. JS is not designed to work with files. If you can't use canvas or make it on server side maybe flash will be solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a well documented base64 encoder/decoder http://hellerim.net/base64_src.php . I modified this code (see below) so it did not need the "core" class.

```
/// BEGIN_DOC(base64).METHOD(decode)
///
// method RETURNTYPE base64.decode(String inp [, enum outType [, bool safe [, bool lax]]])
//
// Encode input data into a base64 character string.
//
// Function arguments:
//     String inp:           base64 encoded data string to be decoded.
//     enum outType          Optional. This parameter specifies the type of the output and determines
//                           how the input data is to be interpreted.:
//                             0  - binary data; create a byte array (default)
//                             1  - 8-bit character string, assuming 1-byte characters encoded in inp
//                             2  - 16-bit (UniCode) character string, assuming 2-byte 
//                                  characters encoded in inp
//                           If 2 is passed to the function, but the number of base64 characters
//                           is odd, a value of null is returned.
//     bool safe             Optional. If this parameter is set to true, the standard base64 
//                           character set is replaced with a modified version where
//                           the characters '+' and '/' are replaced with '-' and '_',
//                           repectively, in order to avoid problems with file system
//                           namings which otherwise could occur on some systems.
//                           By default, the value of this argument is assumed to be
//                           false.
//     bool lax              Optional. If set to true, the function skips all input characters which
//                           cannot be processed. This includes the character '=', too, if
//                           it is followed by at least one different character before the string
//                           ends. However, if skipping infeasible characters amounts to a number
//                           of allowed base64 characters which is not amultiple of 4,
//                           this is considered an error and null is returned.
//                           If lax is set to false (the default), null is returned
//                           whenever an infeasible character is found.
//                           The purpose of this parameter is to give support in cases
//                           where data has been base64 encoded and later on was folded by
//                           some other software, e.g. '\r\n\'s have been inserted in email.
//                           exchange.
// Return value:             The function's processing result value is stored in a string or in
//                           a byte array before it is returned, depending on the value 
//                           assigned to the type parameter. In each case, the value
//                           maybe empty but not null if no error occurred.
// Errors:                   Whenever an error occurs, null is returned. Parameter values
//                           not defined above are considered errors.
//
/// END_DOC

base64.decode = function(inp, outType, safe, lax) {

  // do some argument checking
  if (arguments.length < 1) return null;
  if (arguments.length < 2) outType = 0; // produce character array by default
  if (outType != 0 && outType != 1 && outType != 2) return null;
  if (arguments.length >= 3 && safe != true && safe != false) return null;
  var sEnc = (arguments.length >= 3 && safe) ? this.encStringS : this.encString;  // select encoding character set
  if (arguments.length >= 4 && lax != true && lax != false) return null;
  var aDec = {};                // create an associative array for decoding
  for (var p = 0; p < sEnc.length; p++) { // populate array
    aDec[sEnc.charAt(p)] = p;
  }
  var out = (outType == 0) ? [] : '';
  lax = (arguments.length == 4 && lax); // ignore non-base64 characters
  var l = 0;               // work area
  var i = 0;               // index into input
  var j = 0;               // sextett counter
  var c = 0;               // input buffer
  var k = 0;               // index into work area
  var end = inp.length;    // one position past the last character to be processed
  var C = '';
  // check input
  if (lax) {
    var inpS = '';         // shadow input
    var ignore = false;    // determines wether '=' must be counted
    var cnt = 0;
    for (var p = 1; p <= inp.length; p++) {    // check and cleanup string before trying to decode
      c = inp.charAt(end - p);
      if (c == '=') {
        if (!ignore) {
          if (++cnt > 1) ignore = true;
        } else {
          continue;
        }
      } else if (undefined != aDec[c]) { // the character is base64, hence feasible
        if (!ignore) ignore = true;      // no more '=' allowed
        inpS = c + inpS;                 // prepend c to shadow input
      }
    }
    for (var p = 0; p <= cnt; p++) {     // at most cnt '=''s were garbage, a number in 
      if (p == 2) return null;           // [inpS.length, inpS.length + cnt] must be a
      if ((inpS.length + cnt) % 4 == 0) break;  // multiple of 4
    }
    if (inpS.length % 4 == 1) return null;   // must be 0, 2, or 3 for inpS to contain correctly base64 encoded data
    inp = inpS;                          // inp now contains feasible characters only
    end = inp.length;
  } else {
    if (inp.length % 4 > 0) return null;   // invalid length
    for (var p = 0; p < 2; p++) {        // search for trailing '=''s
      if (inp.charAt(end - 1) == '=') {
        end--;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  // convert
  for (i = 0; i < end; i++) {
    l <<= 6;                             // clear space for next sextett
    if (undefined == (c = aDec[inp.charAt(i)])) return null; // lax must be false at this place!
    l |= (c & 0x3f);    // append it
    if (j == 0) {
      j++;
      continue;                          // work area contains incomplete byte only
    }
    if (outType == 2) {
      if (k == 1) {                      // work area contains complete double byte
        out += String.fromCharCode(l >> (2 * (3 - j)));  // convert leftmost 16 bits and append them to string
        l &= ~(0xffff << (2 * (3 - j)));       // clear the 16 processed bits
      }
      k = ++k % 2;
    } else {                             // work area contains complete byte
      if (outType == 0) {
        out.push(l >> (2 * (3 - j)));          // append byte to array
      } else {
        out += String.fromCharCode(l >> (2 * (3 - j))); // convert leftmost 8 bits and append them to String
      }
      l &= ~(0xff << (2 * (3 - j)));           // clear the 8 processed bits
    }
    j = ++j % 4;                           // increment sextett counter cyclically
  }
  if (outType == 2 && k == 1) return null;  // incomplete double byte in work area

  return out;
}
```

Comment: I have a base64 class for javascript, I'm just having a hard time getting the file contents into the javascript